# batch обработка файлов с пробелами в имени

Tags: bat

нужно пройтись по файлам у которых есть пробелы в именах

```
for %%i in (*.mp3) do 
   ffmpeg -i %%i -codec:a libmp3lame -b:a 128k %%~ni_128.mp3
)
```

скрипт не может найти файл изза пробела. что делать чтобы имя читалось полностью?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте кавычки

```
ffmpeg -i "%%i" -codec:a libmp3lame -b:a 128k "%%~ni"_128.mp3
```

Comment: тоже сейчас додумал `ffmpeg -i "%%i" -codec:a libmp3lame -b:a 128k "%%~ni_128.mp3"`